# How to get the keyboard interrupt from windows IDT with HalGetInterruptVector

Tags: windows, x86-64, masm, keyboardinterrupt

i'm trying to hook windows keyboard interrupt with HalGetInterruptVector however BSOD when call HalGetInterruptVector and i kant hook teh keyboard interrupt in windows IDT. see part of my source code:

```
Start:
PUSH 0
MOV RAX,RSP
PUSH RAX
PUSH RAX
PUSH 1
PUSH 1
PUSH 0
PUSH 1
CALL HalGetInterruptVector ; Here BSOD happens
AND RAX,0FFH
MOV [IRQ1],RAX
```

Why my windows 8 x64 Blue Screen Of Death happens with my code? Where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`HalGetInterruptVector` is an obsolete function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546644(v=vs.85).aspx) and apparently [it is not supported in 64-bit builts of Windows](https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=228458):

> This interface is not supported on 64-bit Windows.
>   Are you trying to port some ancient NT4-style driver to 64-bit platform?
>   It is impossible - you have to re-write it.

---

I'm not familiar with `HalGetInterruptVector` but if your intent is to hook on a specific IRQ maybe that's not a good idea.
Even assuming the function takes the [IOAPIC vs 8059A mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206171/how-sci-system-control-interrupt-vector-is-defined/45233500#45233500) in consideration, a lot of keyboards are not PS/2 (this interface is emulated through [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) though) but are USB.
This means that the IRQ they generate is variable and can even be an [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts).

A better alternative is to hook on the right abstraction level: the [HID class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/).